# devise admin logging out error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i had an issue with devise. whenever i try to log out as an admin with devise, i get the following error

```
No route matches [GET] "/admins/sign_out"
```

doing rake routes, i see it has

```
destroy_admin_session DELETE /admins/sign_out(.:format) devise/sessions#destroy
```

and in my views i call it as...

```
<%= link_to  "sign out as admin", destroy_admin_session_path %>
```

am i supposed to override the admins controller for devise? it seems strange to me that i can go to... /admins/sign_in. however, going to /admins/sign_out doesn't work.

i created the admin using the admin model format.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-role

did anyone else experience this issue as an admin in devise?

thanks

Comment: could you show code form you routes.rb aslo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the sign out URL requires `DELETE` HTTP method.

```
<%= link_to  "sign out as admin", destroy_admin_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

would work.

Comment: This works for me too but I don't understand why we need to pass a delete method when `rake routes` clearly states that it's a `DELETE` method.